# Getting started with reading papers in (philosophical) logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

I have worked through some textbooks thus far, but would like to get started reading papers in the field of logic. Can anyone recommend any papers or how I could get started?
I found that many papers are simply too difficult for me to read, but I don't want to just do textbooks logic exercises but actually read papers etc.

If you could recommend some academic papers & maybe some Stanford Encyclopedia Articles as background reading, that would be really great! As of now I find modal logic particularly interesting, but I welcome anything that discusses logic in a philosophical context that is somewhat accessible to a beginner (albeit not an absolute beginner).

Comment: I always recommend 'Aristotle's De Interpretatione: Contradiction and Dialectic' by CWA Whittaker.

Comment: A fascinating paper that is *philosophically* immensely challenging, but *technically* relatively elementary is:
Popper K, Miller DW. Why Probabilistic Support is not Inductive. *Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences.* 1987;321(1562):569-591. doi:10.1098/rsta.1987.0033. This paper spawned a great controversy, and on that account could open up a world of additional reading, at various levels of difficulty to suit your taste.

Comment: @PeterJ Is this a paper or a book? Also, as I understand it this is about the history of logic, i.e. Aristotelean logic?

Comment: J.Burgess' [Philosophical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=k32w3_wjBoYC&printsec=frontcover), W.V.Quine, [Philosophy of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=GxlUEyI-6JoC&printsec=frontcover), D.Jacquette, [Logic and How it Gets That Way](https://books.google.it/books?id=wkuPBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: See also Penelope Rush (editor), [The Metaphysics of Logic](Penelope Rush (editor)-The Metaphysics of Logic-Cambridge (2014)), Cambridge (2014)

Comment: For Stanford EP, see [Logic and Ontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-ontology/) and [Logical Constants](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-constants/) and [Logical Form](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-form/) and [Logical Consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence/).

Comment: Also Penelope Maddy, [The philosophy of logic](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1352802979), BSL (2012)

Comment: @George Welder - It's a book that explains the small print to the laws of thought and does so very clearly. I like it because it is basic and puts the foundations in place. Many philosophers would benefit from reading it since many do not use the rules correctly and so turn philosophy into a muddle.

Comment: I'd also mention John Corcoran who is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

The layout of this book is quite appealing - Nicholas J. Smith, Logic: The Laws of Truth (2012, Princeton University Press)

https://books.google.com.au/books?id=oGgZWwA2dIgC

For your reference, here is a link to the author's personal website, with papers - 6th from the top in the right-hand side column, is a paper I am looking at now, for my own interest, called "A theory of propositions" from 2016.

Hope you find something of value in either of these two places.

Comment: My problem is, that I only ever find textbooks on logic when I google these things, but I am looking for something that discusses logic and goes over the philosophical aspects of logic, albeit an introductory text.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start with the philosophical aspects of logic for beginners/intermediates is Susan Haack, Philosophy of Logics, 1978.

After that, I would start with the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy articles on the particular topics of interest, as others have said.